# Node.js - Impossible to store the expected data with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a website but I have a big problem with the output.

I wish to recover a name on a site, **it finds me the data but when I try to store this value I can only store the value "null".**

I am a beginner in programming and I have not studied promises, callbacks and async but I think this is strongly related to the problem.

### This is my Node.js code when I use `.text()`

```
const http = require('follow-redirects/http');
const https = require('follow-redirects/https');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

https.get('https://www.example.com/search?q=' + entreprise, response => {
  response.on('data', chunk => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(chunk, {
      xmlMode : false
    });

    domaine = $('div#presentationlien.FichePresentation__link.mt-13 p.fs-12 a.Link').text()

    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(domaine))

    console.log(domaine);

  });

}).on('error', err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

### The HTML :

```
    ...
    <div id="synthese" class="break-word mt-29">
        <p class="fs-12">
            <a class="lien" href="/societe/renault-sas-780129987.html">RENAULT SAS</a>, soci&#xFFFD;t&#xFFFD; par actions simplifi&#xFFFD;e est active depuis 48 ans.<br>Localis&#xFFFD;e &#xFFFD; BOULOGNE-BILLANCOURT (92100), elle est sp&#xE9;cialis&#xE9;e dans le secteur d&apos;activit&#xFFFD; de la construction de v&#xFFFD;hicules automobiles. Son effectif comprends plus de 10 000 salari&#xE9;s.
        </p>


        <div id="presentationlien" class="FichePresentation__link mt-13"> 
            <p class="fs-12">Sur l&apos;ann&#xE9;e 2018 elle r&#xE9;alise un chiffre d&apos;affaires de <span class="synthesenumber">48333000000,00  EU</span>.</p>
            <p class="fs-12">Le total du bilan a augment&#xE9; de 0,97 % entre 2017 et 2018.</p>

            
            <p class="fs-12">Societe.com recense <a class="Link" href="#etab"><span id="synthnbetab" class="synthesenumber">219</span> &#xE9;tablissements <span id="synthnbetabexact"></span></a> et 4 <a class="Link" href="#event">&#xE9;v&#xE9;nements</a> notables depuis un an.</p>
            

            
            <p class="fs-12">
            <a class="Link" href="https://dirigeant.societe.com/dirigeant/Jean-Dominique.SENARD.69230073.html">Jean-Dominique SENARD</a>, est pr&#xFFFD;sident de la soci&#xFFFD;t&#xFFFD; RENAULT SAS.
            </p>
            

            
        </div>

            
            
    </div>
...
```

### The data I want to get :

Jean-Dominique SENARD

```
<p class="fs-12">
            <a class="Link" href="https://dirigeant.societe.com/dirigeant/Jean-Dominique.SENARD.69230073.html">Jean-Dominique SENARD</a>, est pr&#xFFFD;sident de la soci&#xFFFD;t&#xFFFD; RENAULT SAS.
            </p>
```

### The output console :

```
219 établissements événementsJean-Dominique SENARD
```

But when I try to store "Jean-Dominique SENARD" data in a variable to manipulate it, I can't because it returns "undefined" or "null".

Can you please help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a promise based approach, this gives the most readable code IMHO.

You can return a promise from the retrieval function.

I would also suggest using the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, this further improves readability.

Once you have the result you can further manipulate it in testGetRequiredData()..

You could also try replacing the line:

```
domaine = $('div#presentationlien.FichePresentation__link.mt-13 p.fs-12 a.Link').text();
```

with

```
domaine = $('div#presentationlien.FichePresentation__link.mt-13 p.fs-12 a.Link').last().text();
```

This will give just the name (however this may not be as robust!)

For example:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const http = require('follow-redirects/http');
const https = require('follow-redirects/https');

function getRequiredData(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, response => {
            response.on('data', chunk => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(chunk, { xmlMode : false });
                domaine = $('div#presentationlien.FichePresentation__link.mt-13 p.fs-12 a.Link').text()
                resolve(domaine);
            });
        }).on('error', err => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

async function testGetRequiredData(entreprise) {
    try { 
        const url = `https://www.example.com/search?q=${entreprise}`;
        let result = await getRequiredData(url);
        // Do whatever you wish with the result..
        console.log("Result:", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`testGetRequiredData: An error occurred:`, error);
    }
}

// Replace the parameter here..
testGetRequiredData("put entreprise here!");
```

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch modules insted htt & https.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Safiresh! Certainly, we're not tied to any one module.. a promise-based one would be best.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 elements with class `p.fs-12 a.Link`. So if you want to select the 2nd one, you should use another cheerio methods.

Also `.text()` is used to retrieve text value from html element. You should not use it if you want to get html element itself.

Query you need is:

```
$('div#presentationlien.FichePresentation__link.mt-13 p.fs-12 a.Link').eq(2).parent();
```